# No signature of method is applicable for argument types: () values: []Possible solutions:(java.lang.Object), (java.lang.Object)

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a script `User.groovy` and `UserController.groovy`. When I run it, I'm getting

```
Caught: No signature of method: com.vasco.gs.User.addToUserRoles() is applicable for argument types: (com.vasco.gs.Role) values: [nurse] Possible solutions: addToUserRoles(java.lang.Object), addToUserRoles(java.lang.Object), getUserRoles()
```

**My domain class**

```
package com.vasco.gs

import com.vasco.gs.audit.UserAudit

class User {

static constraints = {
    userName blank: false,size:2..25, unique: true
    firstName blank:false, size:2..60,matches:"[a-zA-Z1-9_]+"
    lastName blank:false, size:2..60,matches:"[a-zA-Z1-9_]+"
    middleName nullable:false, blank:false, size:2..60,matches:"[a-zA-Z1-9_]+"
    gender blank : true, nullable:true
    emailId blank : false
    mobileNumber blank : true, nullable:true
    password nullable: false,blank: false,size:2..256,password:true
    confirmPassword nullable: true, blank: false, size:2..256
    activeStatus inList:['Y', 'N']
}

String userName
String password
String confirmPassword
String firstName
String lastName
String middleName
String emailId
String mobileNumber
Gender gender
String activeStatus = 'Y'

static hasMany = [userRoles:UserRole, userLocations: UserLocation]

static transients = [
    'confirmPassword',
    'activeUsers'
]

static List getActiveUsers(){
    return User.findAllByActiveStatus('Y')
}

def beforeInsert() {
    password = password.encodeAsSHA()
}

def activate(){
    this.activeStatus = 'Y'
}

def inactivate(){
    this.activeStatus = 'N'
}

def roles() {
    return userRoles.collect { it.role }
}

def locations() {
    return userLocations.collect { it.location }
}

List addToUserRoles(role){
    UserRole.link this, role
    return roles()
}

List removeFromUserRoles(role){
    UserRole.unLink this, role
    return roles()
}

List addToUserLocations(location){
    UserLocation.link this, location
    return locations()
}

List removeFromUserLocations(location){
    UserLocation.unLink this, location
    return locations()
}

String toString() {
    "$firstName"
}

}
```

**My Controller**

```
class UserController {

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

def UserService

def index() {
    redirect(action: "list", params: params)
}

def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.max(max ?: User.count(), 1)
    [userInstanceList: User.list(params), userInstanceTotal: User.count()]
}

def create() {
    [roleList: Role.list(),locationList: Location.list(),userInstance: new User(params)]
}

def save() {
    def userInstance = new User(params)
    def userRole = params.userRoles
    userRole.each {
        def userrole = Role.get(it)
        println userrole
        def userRoles = userInstance.addToUserRoles(userrole)
        }

    if(UserService.validatePassword(userInstance,params.confirmPassword)){
        if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [userInstance: userInstance, userRoles:userRoles])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [
            message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'),
            userInstance.id
        ])
        redirect(action: "list")

    }
    else
        render(view: "create", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
}
```

I've added

```
def userRole = params.userRoles
userRole.each {
    def userrole = Role.get(it)
    println userrole
    def userRoles = userInstance.addToUserRoles(userrole)
}
```

this code in my user controller...

Comment: Why have you written your own `List addToUserRoles(role)`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by not using the spring security plugin in the way it was intended?

Comment: Instead of List addToUserRoles(role) (duck typing) please try List addToUserRoles(Role role) (explicit typing) as signature to avoid confusion with overloading. It is difficult tell where the things are going wrong but this might help you...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's some sort of clash between your explicit `addToUserRoles` method taking an `Object` parameter and the implicit one taking a `UserRole` parameter that GORM adds to support the `hasMany` declaration.  Try using different names for your explicit methods to avoid interfering with GORM, for example

```
List addRole(role){
    UserRole.link this, role
    return roles()
}

List removeRole(role){
    UserRole.unLink this, role
    return roles()
}

List addLocation(location){
    UserLocation.link this, location
    return locations()
}

List removeLocation(location){
    UserLocation.unLink this, location
    return locations()
}
```

Comment: sorry Ian, could you please explain me a little detailed

Comment: what i'm doing here is i have two domain classes user and role with many-many relationship between them, for many-many relationship one intermediate class will be generated that is UserRole..in User class, i have  "static hasMany = [userRoles:UserRole, userLocations: UserLocation]" and in Role class, i have "static hasMany = [userRoles:UserRole]" and in UserRole class, i have static belongsTo=[user:User, role:Role].. In User class i'm adding Role class object to User class for doing this i have addToUserRoles(role) so in controller save() must also have this same method

Comment: i can understand that both methods had clashes each other, sorry i'm not that good at English

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Making sure the relationship was correctly coded on both sides of the objects fixed it.  Here's a link to the GORM doc describing 1:m, m:m, and 1:1 coding setup.

http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Domain are different of your database, try to change the Datasource.groovy to create-drop again to recreate the tables.